# cannot find C# netcore controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I have added a netcore controller in my existing IdentityServer4 project. Here is my code

```
namespace IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI
{
  public class VersionController : Controller
  {
    IVersionService _repository;
    public VersionController(IVersionService repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    [HttpGet(nameof(GetBackgroundId))]
    public IActionResult GetBackgroundId()
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(_repository.GetBackgroundId());
    }
    [HttpPut(nameof(SetBackgroundId))]
    public IActionResult SetBackgroundId([FromQuery]int id)
    {
        _repository.SetBackgroundId(id);
        return new NoContentResult();
    }
 }
}
```

I also have the following line of code in startup.cs

```
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

I can access the account controller by the following url

```
http://localhost:5001/account/login
```

However, I cannot access the version controller by the following url:

```
http://localhost:5001/version/GetBackgroundId
```

The error code is 404.

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you show content of routeconfig file

Comment: There is no routeconfig file. I added `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a route prefix for controller. You are using attribute routing so you need to include the entire desired route.

The current `GetBackgroundId` controller action would map to

```
http://localhost:5001/GetBackgroundId
```

Add a route to the controller

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class VersionController : Controller {
    IVersionService _repository;
    public VersionController(IVersionService repository) {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    //Match GET version/GetBackgroundId
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult GetBackgroundId() {
        return Ok(_repository.GetBackgroundId());
    }

    //Match PUT version/SetBackgroundId?id=5
    [HttpPut("[action]")]
    public IActionResult SetBackgroundId([FromQuery]int id) {
        _repository.SetBackgroundId(id);
        return NoContent();
    }
 }
```

Also note the use of route tokens and that instead of newing up the responses, `Controller` already has helper methods that provide those results.

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: I figured out this after I posted. This is the solution.